# Android automation using APPIUM framework

Tags: python, android-testing, appium

Somebody said to me 'python does not do automation for android app, as the python stack does not exist in android OS'.

Is it true?
Is Appium based on Android instrumentation framework?
Are there any drawbacks of using Python for writing my test cases? Should I use some other language?

Answer (score 1):

Appium for Android is based on the UIAutomator framework. Selendroid is based on instrumentation.

There are no drawbacks to using python, Appium works with all languages with Selenium/WebDriver bindings which includes python, node.js, objective-c, java, c#, ruby, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe appium dose not have any drawback if python is used. I suggest to use JAVA as a lot of examples and Q/A can be found on web easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java or python to drive Appium, they do the same thing.

And I use python to write [AppiumBoot](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot) framework, It use yaml to run Appium auto test. It makes using Appium very simple, and no need to write java or python code.

[demo video](https://www.zhihu.com/zvideo/1542517089130147840)

[demo code](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot/tree/main/example)

some code like

```
# AppiumBoot/example/material/comp5.yml
# home page: click 5th cell
- click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[5]/android.widget.LinearLayout # 按钮的xpath路径
  sleep: 1
# second page: click 3th demo
- click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]
# thirth page: drag and move
  move_track: '360,1100;360,600;800,600;800,1600;100,1600;100,600'
# back to second page: click 4th demo
- back:
  click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout[4]
  swipe_up:
```